# package kafka.producer does not exist after changing to kafka_2.11

Tags: maven, apache-spark, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have changed to Kafka version from 2.10 to 2.11 in pom file, now I am getting below error

changes in pom
from

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId> . 
<artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
<version>0.9.0-kafka-2.0.1</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
<artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0-cdh6.2.0</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) on project

package kafka.producer does not exist

Comment: You should only need `<artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>` to use the producer API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scala clients (which `kafka.producer` was a part of) have been deprecated for years and have been removed.

If you intend to modernize your code you should change your dependency to `kafka-clients` and refactor it to use the java ones.

Be aware that there is no good "live" migration path between scala consumers (that store offsets in ZK) and the newer java consumers (that store offsets in kafka) - see [KIP-125](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-125%3A+ZookeeperConsumerConnector+to+KafkaConsumer+Migration+and+Rollback) for the details